# What is Virtual Rack?

Tags: hosting, dedicated-server

I was looking for a good dedicated servers hosting but I found one of the providers offering virtual rack and gave good specifications with good price too, I looked for it and all what I found is marketing articles nothing useful, what I understood it is a virtualized environment but what it differs from other virtualization technologies.

Can you help me in this one please?

Comment: it never hurts to ask the provider what are they providing :)

Comment: Sounds like marketing doublespeak, right up there with "cloud computing"

Comment: @Javier I did and their answer is the same to the one I marked and as @Chris S pointed it was a marketing stuff, made me more confusion to me then a clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of providers do this by offering you a dedicated server with a connection to the Internet, and a private VLAN connection between your other machines - making your own 'virtual' rack.

Answer (score -2):

It is a poor brother of the bladeservers [multiple hardware servers stacked vertically in one ~20U box]. Instead of buying a box of servers, you're buying a group of servers installed all places over DC and connected by 100mbit, and lose 20% on power.